# Having multiple artboard on the same window

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, artboard

Like you can have multiple artboard on the same window in Adobe Illustrator, is it possible to have multiple working areas on the *same window* for Inkscape (instead of duplicating the current window)?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  No. Inkscape doesn't support multiple artboards/pages.

Comment: @billy Aah i see.Thanks for the info!

Comment: Note that you can put objects outside the page area in Inkscape. So this might work if you just need to have the graphics somewhere you can easily access them, all within the same document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inkscape has no multi artboard/page support.

However, there are some possible workarounds.

It's entirely possible to have objects outside the page area. This could be useful if you just need them to be easily accessible.

With a bit more effort, it would be possible to change the Document Properties, to hide the Page Border, and change the background colour to grey. Then you could construct "psuedo-pages" from a white rectangle grouped with the content.  Obviously, when outputting a final SVG or PNG, you would have to select the psuedo-page, and do *Edit > Resize page to selection*, and possibly delete the white rectangle before outputting if you don't want a white background..

Here's an example showing a set up with pseudo-pages made from groups.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some people use layers for this - you can hide and show layers (e.g. all except the current one) in the layers dialog.